# Drupal nodewords problem!! Won't save "other pages" custom meta tags. Is it a bug?

Tags: drupal, module, seo, meta-tags

I recently started to use the Nodewords module in Drupal 6. This adds the posibility to add metatags and optimize your site for SEO in a very fashionable way, very nice, BUT, it has a problem...
probably a bug or something. 
Downloaded the version

http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/nodewords-6.x-1.11.zip

When I go into configuring the module I want to specify custom metas for the pages that i have defined on the views (paths)
So of course this can be acieved with :
admin/content/nodewords/meta-tags/other  **(Tab Other pages)**

IT doesn't save my content, well, partially, it loads the default metas (already done that), when I click save, and if I go to edit again...it won't save them...keeps showing me the defaults ..
same thing resembles on the site itself, very very anoying as i have many custom pages set.

Is it a bug? did anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is here:

http://drupal.org/node/673214

You need to patch nodewords module.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to Nodewords 1.13 or newer, it's a known problem that Nodwords 1.11 did not load what was saved for custom pages (amongst other Major Snafus).